# Delete a cudaMalloc allocated memory inside kernel

Tags: cuda

I want to delete an array allocated by `cudaMalloc` inside a kernel using `delete[]`; but memory checker shows access violation, array is kept in memory and kernel continues to execute.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__global__ void kernel(int *a)
{
    int *b = new int[10];

    delete[] b; // no violation

    delete[] a; // Memory Checker detects access violation.
}

int main()
{
    int *d_a;
    cudaMalloc(&d_a, 10 * sizeof(int));

    kernel<<<1, 1>>>(d_a);

    return 0;
}
```

1. What is the difference between memory allocated by `cudaMalloc` and `new` in device code?
2. Is it possible to delete memory allocated by `cudaMalloc` in device code?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `cudaMalloc` in host code and `new` (or `malloc`) in device code allocate out of logically separate areas.  The two areas are not generally interoperable from an API standpoint.
2. no

You may wish to read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations).  The description given there for in-kernel `malloc` and `free` generally applies to in-kernel `new` and `delete` as well.